# git subfolder into branch keeping folder links

Tags: git, subdirectory

Master branch have below folder structure:

- Common

  - a.txt
- Module

  - ABC

    - abc.txt
  - DEF

    - def.txt

Now i want to create a new branches from master with sub-directory into new branches like below:

1. Common Branch should have Common folder & a.txt under its folder

   - Common

     - a.txt
2. ABC branch should have stucture like Module\ABC\abc.txt

   - Module

     - ABC

       - abc.txt
3. DEF branch should have structure like Module\DEF\def.txt

   - Module

     - DEF

       - def.txt

After modification into Common, ABC & DEF branches want to merge back to master.

Comment: Can i use git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter?

Answer (score 0):

You can create 3 different branches based on `master` and then delete two subdirectories from each of them so that you can have 3 separate branches with each subdirectory in it. Besides, you will be able to maintain the history too of that subdirectory.

```
git branch --no-track "$subdirectory1" master
git checkout "$subdirectory1"
git push --set-upstream --progress origin
```

Merging `ABC` and `DEF` again in `master` will not give anything but might lead to conflicts. Because the `master` structure will have `Common`, `ABC` and `DEF`. The newly created `ABC` will not have `common` and `DEF` and will result in deleting the `Common` and `DEF` from `master`.

However for merging you can use.

```
git checkout master
git merge subdirectory1
```

Comment: I want to keep the history & merge back to master

Comment: If other sub folders are deleted & pushed only subdirectory1  folder into subdirectory1 branch this history will also get merged into master branch right?

Comment: yes thats right that SHA from subdirectory1 will be in master's history too.